# How to create a new workspace file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, file

I was moving around my Xcode folder project and I have accidentally deleted the .xcworkspace file (the white one). Is it possible to generate a new one?

Comment: go to trash and put it back

Comment: i have deleted it from the trash too, that's the problem

Comment: good job , you can try to run pod init , install pods again after deleting podFile sure after coping the content inside it

Comment: Running `pod install` is a good suggestion. For the future I recommend using some kind of version control, like git.

Comment: File->New->Workspace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have suggested, source control would be a great idea if you're not using it already, to protect you in this precise scenario. [Github](http://github.com) is a great place to start for that.

### To create a new Xcode workspace

In the Xcode menu, click File > New > Workspace, then follow the prompts.

[image]

Once that's done, you'll have an empty Workspace, and you can drag whichever .xcodeproj files in that you wish to the sidebar to add them to the workspace.

[image]